# Triple Nested Big O with dependent indices

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am working on finding the Big O to this problem, and I am having difficulty with the third nested loop. Here is the code

```
for (int i = 1 to n)
  for (int j = i to n)
    for (int k = j*j to n)
      //some constant operation
```

The *i* forloop is clearly O(n).

The *j* forloop is (n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 2 + 1) = (n-1)n/2 = O(n^2).

But I am unsure on how to consider the *k* forloop. I know for one full loop of *j* (1 to n), the summation is something like (n + n-4 + n-6 + ...) = sum_{k=1}^n (n - k^2), but I am unsure on where to go from there.

Any advice on how to proceed would be great!

Comment: I think your suggested summation is wrong. You say it should be `(n + (n - 4) + (n - 6) + ... )`, but it should be `(n - 9)` instead of `(n - 6)`.

Comment: Hint: Can you reduce the upper limit of the `j` loop without changing the resulting big O complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `j` is greater than sqrt(n), the inner loop isn't entered. The same is true when `i` is greater than sqrt(n), because `j` starts at `i`.

Therefore, we can split the work done into two cases:

- On iterations where `i` and/or `j` are more than `sqrt(n)`: the `k` loop isn't entered, and it's not difficult to prove that the time complexity done by the outer two loops is Theta(n^2).
- On iterations where both `i` and `j` are less than `sqrt(n)`: The first two loops run up to `sqrt(n)` times each, and the last loop runs up to n times, therefore the upper bound of the number of total iterations is `O(sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) * n) = O(n^2)`.

In both cases, the upper bound is O(n^2), and the first case shows that it is also a lower bound. Therefore, the total time complexity is Theta(n^2).

Comment: That seems to make sense, but when running a program to test the number of times i am in the k loop, I am getting something much lower than the theoretical limit. For example, I am getting an order of magnitude lower for the program versus theoretical. Is that okay? Why does that happen?

Comment: @GentleSaint The number of times doesn't mean anything because there's a constant factor involved in Big O. But if you take a large n and check the number of iterations for n and for 2n, you should see that it is about 4 times as large for 2n.

Comment: Yep, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: The 3rd loop runs exactly `1*(n - 1*1 + 1) + 2*(n - 2*2 + 1) + 3*(n - 3*3 + 1) + ... + floor(sqrt(i))*(n - i*i + 1)` times, which is less than the number of times the 2nd loop runs.